# Maha Deva as Trivishtapa : The Three Paths of Swarga, Mrityu and Paatala Lokas

Tags: mahabharata, shiva

Maha Deva is also caled " Trivishtapa " or the Provider of the Three Paths of Swarga, Mrityu and Paatala Lokas.

What are Swarga, Mrityu and Paatala Lokas?

Comment: Mrityu loka is the earth. Other two Heaven and Hell.

Comment: @Rickross please place it in a nice way as a full answer so we can close it